# c++ inline function wrapping single vmovups in GCC inline assembly

Tags: c++, assembly, clang, inline, avx

I'm trying to work around an apparent bug in the clang compiler where using the AVX intrinsic _mm256_loadu_ps results in unnecessary instructions being output in assembly. In particular, first it does a vmovups on the first half of the input vector into an xmm register, then joins the second half with the first using a vinsertf128 instruction, slowing down the program a bit. I would instead expect a single vmovups instruction to a compiler allocated ymm register.

I'm always been comfortable with SSE/AVX intrinsics, but as soon as I need to drop down to inline assembly I'm lost.

I'd like an inline function that does the same as the following, but the vmovups should be in inline assembly.

```
inline __mm256 V8fLoadU(const float* pf)
{
    return _mm256_loadu_ps(pf);
}
```

Here's what I've tried so far, but it doesn't work (seems to move *pf single float onto the stack, then it loads that space):

```
inline __mm256 V8fLoadU(const float* pf)
{
    __m256 m;
    __asm__("vmovups %1, %0" : "=x" (m) : "xm" (pf));
    return m;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not a bug, it's done on purpose. On contemporary x86 architectures, 256-bit unaligned accesses can be very slow in some cases. Slow enough, in fact, that it's faster to do 2 128-bit accesses and stitch them together, as you're seeing clang do here. Depending upon the details of your particular access pattern, it may be slightly faster to do the 256-bit unaligned accesses, but the compiler only has so much information to go on when it synthesizes the code. If you use aligned accesses, you should always see 256-bit move instructions.

Comment: 90% of the time at least, the data going into this function will already be aligned anyway. After doing a performance comparison of aligned vs unaligned loads using a different compiler that emits the single vmovups instruction, I've found the performance to be pretty much the same as using the aligned variant as long as the pointers being passed in are pre-aligned.

Comment: There's some info on why 256b loads are split here: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=80568. It is usually avoidable with `-march=whatever` instead of just `-mavx2` ... at least in GCC. Not sure about Clang.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By passing a pointer as the input argument you're loading the value of the pointer rather than what it points to. You need to pass the value you want to load.

```
__m256 V8fLoadU(const float* pf)
{
    __m256 m;
    __asm__("vmovups %1, %0" : "=x" (m) : "m" (*pf));
    return m;
}
```

Comment: @Kumputer It means the operand can be in an XMM/YMM register. It was strictly speaking accurate, VMOVUPS supports register to register moves, but it's not what you want in this case. So with just the "m" constraint it should accept the memory reference as is, and there's no need for a cast since the "m" constraint doesn't care about the referenced type, it only needs to have a representable address.

Comment: Ok, it works! Thanks! That said, the code output looks just like I would expect, but the performance is exactly the same. Well, at least it's saving a register.